# FillRectangle Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, drawing

This is the exception I am getting

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Rectangle rect)
       at frmMain.drawCboxItem(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) in frmMain.cs:line 465
       at frmMain.cboxSectionCell_DrawItem(Object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) in frmMain.cs:line 485
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectDrawItem(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

And the code

```
if (e.Index > -1)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    Brush bgColourBrush = null;
    Brush fgColourBrush = null;
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    objPDT.ListCell pdt = (objPDT.ListCell)combo.Items[e.Index];

    if (e.ForeColor == SystemColors.HighlightText)
    {
        bgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
        fgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
    }
    else if (pdt.bgColour == null)
    {
        bgColourBrush = Brushes.Black;
        fgColourBrush = Brushes.White;
    }
    else
    {
        bgColourBrush = pdt.bgColour;
        fgColourBrush = pdt.fgColour;
    }


        // background
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bgColourBrush, e.Bounds);
        //foreground
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(pdt.Name, combo.Font, fgColourBrush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);

}
```

And finally the values being passed to it:

```
pdt {
    Section 8--> CELL}  objPDT.ListCell
    _bgcolour   {Color = {Color [A=255, R=166, G=166, B=166]}}  System.Drawing.Brush {System.Drawing.SolidBrush}
    _CellID 27  int
    _fgcolour   {Color = {Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}}  System.Drawing.Brush {System.Drawing.SolidBrush}
    _name   "Section 8--> CELL" string
    _SectionID  8   int
    bgColour    {Color = {Color [A=255, R=166, G=166, B=166]}}  System.Drawing.Brush {System.Drawing.SolidBrush}
    fgColour    {Color = {Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}}  System.Drawing.Brush {System.Drawing.SolidBrush}
    Name    "Section 8--> CELL" string
    Value   "8:27"  string
}

e.Bounds    {X = 0 Y = 30 Width = 290 Height = 15}  System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Bottom  45  int
    Height  15  int
    IsEmpty false   bool
    Left    0   int
    Location    {X = 0 Y = 30}  System.Drawing.Point
    Right   290 int
    Size    {Width = 290 Height = 15}   System.Drawing.Size
    Top 30  int
    Width   290 int
    X   0   int
    Y   30  int
```

Comment: You are not calling the Dispose() method of the SolidBrush objects you create.  That does go kaboom in a pretty undiagnosable way when your program has consumed 10,000 GDI Objects.  The garbage collector usually has a hard time keeping you out of trouble like this when you custom-draw.  Use a bool flag that you set to *true* when you use the SolidBrushes and be sure to dispose them after drawing when that flag is set.  Look for other places in your code as well where you might be forgetting to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I had to remove the dispose as that completely broke the script, this was working perfectly until it moved to VS2012

Comment: It will definitely break your code when you dispose brushes *other* than those SolidBrush brushes that you create.  That's why you need to use a bool flag.

Comment: I checked the GDI Objects, it stays at 3187 :S  even with the bool flag set it still happens.  The annoying thing is if the CellID is 0 then it gets painted fine!  So if everything is the same but the string name and int cellid then it gets painted, yet they have nothing to do with this part of the code!

Comment: That's an unreasonably high number.  The GDI object heap is shared with all processes.  The heap itself can get exhausted as well, 65k objects iirc.

Comment: how would you recommend doing the dispose on the above then?

Comment: This is why I recommended "Look for other places in your code".

Comment: @HansPassant apparently causing dispose will break it and you shouldn't dispose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating Brush objects with each draw, perhaps you can make `bgColourBrush` and `fgColourBrush` global variables and then just change their color instead. Please forgive me if the code below doesn't compile as-is, I did this freehand.
Like this:

```
if (e.Index > -1)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    objPDT.ListCell pdt = (objPDT.ListCell)combo.Items[e.Index];

    if (e.ForeColor == SystemColors.HighlightText)
    {
        this.bgColourBrush.Color = e.BackColor;
        this.fgColourBrush.Color = e.ForeColor;
    }
    else if (pdt.bgColour == null)
    {
        this.bgColourBrush.Color = Brushes.Black.Color;
        this.fgColourBrush.Color = Brushes.White.Color;
    }
    else
    {
        this.bgColourBrush.Color = pdt.bgColour;
        this.fgColourBrush.Color = pdt.fgColour;
    }


    // background
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bgColourBrush, e.Bounds);
    //foreground
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(pdt.Name, combo.Font, fgColourBrush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

### UPDATE

So I see that your pdt ListCell object has a `bgColour` and a `fgColour` property. In order for my above solution to work, `bgColour` and `fgColour` need to be of type `Color`. Or if they are type SolidColorBrush, then you need to do this: `bgColour.Color` and `fgColour.Color`.

Comment: The issue was in another part of the code on another form was disposing them.  But your idea is a good one so I'll mark it as the answer as I will move to this approach eventually

Answer (score 2):

You should always dispose unmanaged classes like `Brush`, `SolidBrush`, `Pen`. Assuming the `pdt.bgColour` and `pdt.fgColour` are of type `Color`, something like the following code should prevent that crash. Warning: Untested code.

```
if (e.Index > -1)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    SolidBrush bgColourBrush = null;
    SolidBrush fgColourBrush = null;
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    objPDT.ListCell pdt = (objPDT.ListCell)combo.Items[e.Index];
    try {
        if (e.ForeColor == SystemColors.HighlightText)
        {
            bgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
            fgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        }
        else if (pdt.bgColour == null)
        {
            bgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            fgColourBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            bgColourBrush = pdt.bgColour;
            fgColourBrush = pdt.fgColour;
        }

        // background
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bgColourBrush, e.Bounds);
        //foreground
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(pdt.Name, combo.Font, fgColourBrush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    } finally {
        if(bgColorBrush != null) {
            bgColorBrush.Dispose();
        }
        if(fgColorBrush != null) {
            fgColorBrush.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```